# Windows path with double backslash in Python

Tags: python, string, mkdir, backslash, os.path

This seems to be very basic question but still I am confused. I have a windows path containing backslash, which to escape its special meaning I have used `\\`.
While I use `print` function get the path, gives me the actual return:

```
>>> print("C:\\Users\\2.0Dev\\8\\F000B101\\POD280-51\\Resources")
C:\Users\2.0Dev\8\F000B101\POD280-51\Resources
```

however, when the same is passed as an argument to two different functions in python, the behavior is different :

```
>>> rsrc_dir="C:\\Users\\2.0Dev\\8\\F000B101\\POD280-51\\Resources"
>>> os.path.isdir(rsrc_dir)
>>> False
>>> os.mkdir('C:\\Users\\2.0Dev\\8\\F000B101\\POD280-51\\Resources')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified:'C:\\Users\\2.0Dev\\8\\F000B101\\POD280-51\\Resources'
```

Can someone please explain how the two functions interpret the same parameter. Also, how to return the formatted string same as the `print` function.

Much Thanks.

Comment: Does `C:\\Users\\2.0Dev\\8\\F000B101\\POD280-51\\ ` exist? Does `C:\\Users\\2.0Dev\\8\\F000B101\\ ` exist? Does `C:\\Users\\2.0Dev\\8\\ ` exist? Make sure all earlier directories exist or use `os.markdirs(..)` to create them as well.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Although the intermediary directories do no exist, `mkdir` can create them. I tested it and it wors find on powershell.

Comment: Does this mean python `os.mkdir` and powershell `mkdir` commands behave differently ?

Comment: Why would you assume that powershell and pyhton are the same? os.mkdir**s** creates intermediary directories. os.mkdir _does not_. The documentation is your friend ....

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thanks ! you are correct. I followed the documentation and then got my answer. I did use then `makedirs`  to create the intermediary directories.

Answer (score 2):

`os.mkdir` does not create intermediate catalogs, so this:

```
os.mkdir('C:\\Users\\2.0Dev\\8\\F000B101\\POD280-51\\Resources')
```

would fail if not

```
os.path.exists('C:\\Users\\2.0Dev\\8\\F000B101\\POD280-51')
```

use [os.makedirs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) if you want recursive directory creation. Note that you might use [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) which will use separator appriopiate to system at which it runs, in your case usage would be:

```
rsrc_dir=os.path.join("C:\\","Users","2.0Dev","8","F000B101","POD280-51","Resources")
```